# How to show website elements to all pages in HTML template?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started to work on [small personal project](http://center2.gamblergroup.eu/homepage.html), and have one little issue that don't know how to resolve. I have this code into homepage:

```
<div class="border-bottom bottom-position">
    <!-- social icons start -->
    <div class="social">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="fa fa-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/DeilOfficial/"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fa fa-twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/DeilOfficial"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fa fa-instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/DeilOfficial/"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fa fa-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCzTTmHzjEfJ0UsSirOAG9A?sub_confirmation=1"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fa fa-soundcloud" href="https://soundcloud.com/deilofficial"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form action="subscribe.php" id="subscribe" method="post" name="subscribe1">
        <input style="" class="subscribe-requiredField subscribe-email" id="" name="subscribe-email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
        <a style="" href="#">
            <button class="submit-button-2 rimu1 rimu2" id="submit-2" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
        </a>
    </form>

    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {

            .border-bottom>div {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 661px) {

            .border-bottom {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
            .social {
                float: left;
                padding-left: 40px;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
            form#subscribe {
                float: right;
                padding-right: 40px;

            }
        }


        form#subscribe {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 20px;


        }

        span.subscribe-error {
            color: #fff;
        }

        span.subscribe-error {
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        form#subscribe {
            min-height: 78px;
        }

        .social {
            padding-top: 22px;
        }

        .credits {
            color: #fff;

        }
    </style>
</div>
```

The problem is that subscribe form and social icons are showing only on homepage, and not in other pages. How to show also on other pages in the same place like on homepage?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using only HTML and CSS then you don't have option than copying this code to all other pages. But if you are using any language like PHP Then you can use following way

1. create Separate file called "_bottom.php"
2. Write your code you want to repeat inside above file "_bottom.php"
3. Just render this file in every page where you want same code

I don't know whether you are familier with PHP or not ? but You can use same way for other languages too but not in css html

Comment: All content is in one html file. no separated files. Pls check site into my question. i have included.

Comment: @MartinK I checked with your site , actually you lost the `<div class="border-bottom bottom-position">` div in your website and I can not help you untill I see full scenario here

Comment: Entire HTML code is too large to post here.. Can you check pls into source.?

Comment: @MartinK sure will try my best to help you out just give me some time :)

Comment: Sure, no rush. :)

Comment: @MartinK is this http://deil.cz/artist-page a different website you redirect or it is your creation

Comment: Its different site. This will be used as landing page, nothing more.

Comment: any news? Do you found a way ?

Comment: @MartinK Sorry I was busy with my work yesterday .. and Its difficult to debug through source :( Sorry I couldn't help you